# how includes with css parent number html?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have the following list structure in html:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h1>main title</h1>
        <ol class="father">
            <li>mac</li>
            <li>windows</li>
            <li>linux</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

the result of the previous code is:

[image]

what i need is to add the father's number to ".father> li" and hide the father's number

example:

```
main title
1.1. mac
1.2. windows
1.3. linux
```

I have seen some post but with none I have been able to reach the solution, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following CSS:

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;               
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol.wrapper > li::before {
  visibility:hidden;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;            
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";  
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/o1o3dku7/3/)

Comment: number sill display

Comment: Updated answer to hide the parent's number

Answer (score 1):

This requries css counters

Here's the HTML

```
<ol class="outer">
    <h1>main title</h1>
    <li>
        <ol class="father">
            <li>mac</li>
            <li>windows</li>
            <li>linux</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
ol.outer {
    counter-reset: outer;
}
ol.outer > li {
    position: relative; /* Create a positioning context */
    list-style: none; /* Disable the normal item numbering */
    counter-increment: outer;
}

ol.father {
  counter-reset: father;
}

ol.father > li:before {
    content: counter(outer) "." counter(father);
    counter-increment: father; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
}
```

See the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzp2wvLa/)